# Update SQL Server CE database from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL class with following variables:

```
private SqlCeConnection _objSql = null;
private SqlCeCommand Command = null;
private SqlCeDataAdapter DataApater = null;
private SqlCeCommandBuilder CommandBuilder = null;

public void getTableData(string TableName, ref DataTable Data)
{
    // DataTable Data = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        string strSqlCommand = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", TableName);
        Command = new SqlCeCommand(strSqlCommand, _objSql);
        DataApater = new SqlCeDataAdapter(Command);
        CommandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(DataApater);
        DataApater.Fill(Data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    // return Data;
}
```

Above function is used to get data from the database.

I am using the following code to update:

```
public void DoUpdate(DataTable Data)
{
    try
    {
        DataApater.Update(Data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

But this function is not updating the database.

How to update database from a data grid using `SqlCeConnection`? Please give the exact code if possible.

Comment: I really doubt you want `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`; that will discard the original stack trace and say your method threw the exception. That makes it very hard to diagnose errors.

Answer (score 2):

DataAdapter need to be initialized and the connection configuration to the database needs to be specified to enable the update function.

Check out an example here: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx)